# Time complexity of $T(n) = nT(n-1) + n^2$

Tags: recurrence-relation

This time complexity comes from $N$-queen problem. There are many threads talking about the time complexity to be $O(n!)$ but I cannot figure out how we get it. Here is the progress I have so far:

$$
\begin{align}
T(n) & = n T(n-1) + n^2\\
& = n(n-1)T(n-2) + n(n-1)^2 + n^2\\
& \vdots\\
& = n! + n! + n(n-1) \dots 2^2 + n(n-1) \dots 4*3^2 + \dots + n(n-1)^2 + n^2
\end{align}
$$

RHS and LHS divided by $n!$

$$
    \frac{T(n)}{n!} = 2 + \frac{2}{1!} + \frac{3}{2!} + \dots + \frac{n-2}{(n-3)!} + \frac{n-1}{(n-2)!} + \frac{n}{(n-1)!}
$$

From comments in [GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-set-3-n-queen-problem/) the RHS converges to a constant. Can anyone please explain why the RHS converges to a constant?

Comment: Recurrence relations don't have "time complexity"! The recurrence just defines some function. In this case, you're using that function to measure the running time of some algorithm but it's the algorithm that has that running time, not the mathematical function. (This is analogous to talking about the length of the number 1000 after being told that Paris is 1000km from Berlin.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RHS does converge, you can prove it using the [Ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) which says

> for series of non-zero numbers $\sum a_n$ with $$\rho = \lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$$
>   for $\rho$ finite or infinite follows that
>
> $\rho<1$ series converges absolutely
>
> $\rho> 1$ series diverges
>
> $\rho=1$ inconclusive

In OP's case the ratio 
$$\rho=\frac{(n+1)(n-1)!}{n(n!)}
=\frac{(n+1)(n-1)!}{n^2(n-1)!}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\rho=0$$
Therefore  the series converges.

Answer (score 4):

We can compute the limit explicitly:
$$
1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n+1}{n!} = 1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)!} = 2e + 1.
$$

Answer (score -1):

**(skip to Part II)**

You might find it easier to think about it this way.

First think of the definition of $n!$

$n! = n(n-1)!$

where $1! = 1$

The ! "operator" is just a notation convenience, it might as well have been written as $R(n)$

$R(n) = nR(n-1)$

where $R(1) = 1$

The idea so far is that $n! = R(n)$

Then think of the definition of $T(n)$ and how it relates to $R(n)$ (or $n!$)

$T(n) = nT(n-1) + n^2$

$T(n) > nR(n-1) + n^2 = n! + n^2$

$T(n)$ is greater than $R(n)$ because of the $n^2$ term on every iteration. With this you have already proved that $T(n)$ is at least $O(n!)$

This doesn't proof $T(n)$ is $O(n!)$ as you might need a bigger function.

**Part II**

By the definition of big-O we're now interested in proving there exists constants $c$ and $k$ such that $T(n) \leq cn!$ for $n \geq k$.

$T(n)/n! \leq c$

expanding $T(n)$ you'll find

$T(n)/n! = (nT(n-1) + n^2)/n! = nT_{n-1} / n! + n^2/n! = T_{n-1}/(n-1)! + n^2/n!$

You can expand that a couple more times to realise
$T_n/n! = T_{n-k}/(n-k)! + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{(n-i)^2/(n-i)!}$

With $k = n - 1$ and defining $T_1 = 1$ as the base case:

$T_n/n! = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} {(n-1)^2/(n-1)!}$

The summation term converges (in each "iteration" it grows less and less), that guarantees that if we find a $c$ for a given $k$, then it will also work for all $n \geq k$. To find $c$, just substitute $n$ on the above equation for any value you'd like $k$ to have.

Comment: This doesn't work. You've argued that $T(n)\geq n!$ but the question asks us to show that $T(n)\leq c\,n!$ for some constant $c$ (and for large enough $n$, if necessary).

Comment: thanks @DavidRicherby, you are completely right, I've modified my answer accordingly, hoping not to make any mistake this time or assuming stuff I shouldn't have.